# Problems with forwarding HTTPS to another host by url path

Tags: ssl, haproxy, forwarding

I am trying to use haproxy to forward https traffic from one host to another when the url path begins with "/special-path" (Ex: www.mysite1.com/special-path/3)

With the following setup, I actually have it working 10% of the time.  It seems to timeout regularly, but occasionally a few requests squeeze by--which makes me thing that my haproxy config is not at all sound.

My setup:

On host1, haproxy (configured with tls) is running, and all traffic to www.mysite1.com comes here.
On host2, there is a webserver running on port 3000 (but without ssl, I am wanting haproxy to terminate ssl to avoid setting it up on the web service)

On the first host, my haproxy.conf has the following:

```
frontend www-http
    bind *:80
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ http
    use_backend www-special-backend if { path_beg /special-path }

frontend www-https
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/private/mysite1.com.pem
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
    use_backend www-special-backend if { path_beg /special-path }

backend www-special-backend
    mode http
    server www-special-1 172.11.11.111:3000      check
```

My understanding is that with this setup on host1, https://www.mysite1.com/special-path/2 will forward the traffic to 172.11.11.111 on port 433

Now on the 172.11.11.111 host, I have haproxy (configured with tls) with the following:

```
frontend www-http
    bind *:80
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ http
    use_backend www-special-backend if { path_beg /special-path }

frontend www-https
    log global
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/private/mysite1.com.pem
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
    use_backend www-special-backend if { path_beg /special-path }

backend www-special-backend
    redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
    option httpclose
    server www-special-1 *:3000     check
```

Comment: why do you have two haproxy on two hosts? can you check your post??

Comment: As of now, both hosts can serve content via https, so both hosts need haproxy.  But even if you ignore the haproxy for 172.11.11.111, do you see anything that would prevent https://www.mysite1.com/special-path/2 from hitting 172.11.11.111:3000/special-path/2 ???  That is my main problem.  It isn't working.

Comment: add `    mode http` into `frontend`

Comment: Does your 2nd backend `172.11.11.111:3000` serves content on HTTPS? Also, you don't need `redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }` in your second config.